# How to flatten a list of dicts into one dict in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to be able to take a dataframe like this with a `features` column containing a list of dicts:

```
{"id": 1, "label": 1, "features": [{"key1": 1}, {"key2": "dog"}, {"key4": "jane"}]}
{"id": 3, "label": 0, "features": [{"key3": 3}, {"key1": 3}]}
{"id": 4, "label": 1, "features": [{"key1": 4}, {"key2": "bird"}]}
{"id": 2, "label": 1, "features": [{"key2": 2}, {"key3": 2}]}
{"id": 5, "label": 0, "features": [{"key2": "cat"}, {"key3": 5}]}
{"id": 6, "label": 1, "features": [{"key3": 6}, {"key1": 6}]}
```

and flatten the list to one dict:

```
{"id": 1, "label": 1, "features": {"key1": 1, "key2": "dog", "key4": "jane"}}
{"id": 3, "label": 0, "features": {"key3": 3, "key1": 3}}
{"id": 4, "label": 1, "features": {"key1": 4, "key2": "bird"}}
{"id": 2, "label": 1, "features": {"key2": 2, "key3": 2}}
{"id": 5, "label": 0, "features": {"key2": "cat", "key3": 5}}
{"id": 6, "label": 1, "features": {"key3": 6, "key1": 6}}
```

In the actual data there will be hundreds of keys, so I'd like to avoid explicitly naming them in the code. I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. ChatGPT rabbit hole didn't get me anywhere. Any help appreciated!

Comment: is it a spark dataframe? if so, what's the data type of the column?

Comment: It is a Spark Dataframe, yes. The type is going to be an array of map types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map_from_entries`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries.html#pyspark.sql.functions.map_from_entries) is probably the function you need. When you load this JSON in dataframe, your *features* column will be an array of structs, so you just do:

```py
df.withColumn("features", map_from_entries(col("features")))
```

Comment: This seems like it should work but in my actual dataset, it gives me the following error: ```Exception has occurred: AnalysisException
cannot resolve 'map_from_entries(`features`)' due to data type mismatch: '`features`' is of array<map<string,string>> type. map_from_entries accepts only arrays of pair structs.;
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out that it does work if the list is structs, not maps. I was able to convert my list of maps to list of structs and now this works.